# Safari 6 won't play .mov files

Tags: html, video, safari, .mov

I'm pulling my hair here trying to figure out why Safari (v6) won't play .mov files.
This is my setup, simplified -

```
<video width="800" height="450" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="example.mov" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser can't play this video.
</video>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is uploading movie clips to a WordPress blog from an iPhone. iPhone saves video in .mov with h264 encoding (correct?). It would be too much of a hassle for the client to render other formats as well when uploading, and we decided to settle with this format.
In Chrome, I can see this video but in Safari it won't play, even when accessing the file directly. The player simply displays its UI bar with a loading statement. I get no errors.
I've also made sure to set the .htaccess file to include AddType for .mov / quicktime.
What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please put this example online? Be good to examine this `example.mov` with [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).

IOS Safari seems very sensitive how MP4s are encoded. Only thing I've found that works for me is the `libx264-ipod640.ffpreset` with ffmpeg. See https://github.com/kaihendry/recordmydesktop2.0 for more.